# Detecting touch events during the device rotation transition

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, ios8, uiinterfaceorientation, uitouch

In iOS 8, touch events are not detected while the transition to the trait collection happens. Our app gets user touch input regularly, but some touches are skipped during the device rotation.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog("touch!");
}
```

I tried to add the statement as below, but it didn't work.

```
- (void)willTransitionToTraitCollection:(UITraitCollection *)newCollection withTransitionCoordinator:(id)coordinator {
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}
```

Is there any way to detect touch event during the device rotation transition?